# Ambiguous column name 'Chem_Num'

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute my SQL I get an error

> Ambiguous column name 'Chem_Num'

What should I do about this?

I tried this for my code and I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
SELECT 
    Chem_Num, Chem_Retail_Name, 
    Carried_Num as "Item Carry", 
    Tech_LName as "Driver",
    Job_Num, Used_Qty AS "Used on Job", 
    (Carried_Outbound - Carried_Return) AS "Gone from Truck" 
FROM
    PEPS.CHEMICAL 
JOIN 
    PEPS.CARRIED ON CHEMICAL.Chem_Num = CARRIED.Chem_Num
JOIN 
    PEPS.ASSIGNMENT ON CARRIED.Assign_Num = ASSIGNMENT.Assign_Num
JOIN 
    PEPS.TECHNICIAN ON ASSIGNMENT.Tech_Num = TECHNICIAN.Tech_Num
JOIN 
    PEPS.USED ON CHEMICAL.Chem_Num = USED.Chem_Num
WHERE
    Chem_Num IN (101, 103, 107) 
ORDER BY 
    Chem_Num ASC, Carried_Num ASC;
```

Comment: You're joining multiple tables. How many of them have a column named `Chem_Num`? It looks like at least TWO: `CHEMICAL.Chem_Num=CARRIED.Chem_Num`. You need to specify which one you want to see in your `select` results.

Comment: A best practice in multi-table queries is to qualify column names, perhaps using table aliases.

Answer (score 3):

It means that more than one of the tables you joined has a Chem_Num column, so the query doesn't know which one you want.

You'll have to prefix the column name with the table it's coming from, like you did in that join: `CHEMICAL.Chem_Num=USED.Chem_Num`